# SuiteScript 2.0 setting bin number (binnumber) on Inventory Details Throws INVALID_FLD_VALUE

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a script that was working create. The method takes in a sales order id and at some point sets a bin number on a inventory details. This method works when used in one of our scripts, but when used in a another script it throws an error INVALID_FLD_VALUE. Is there some value that needs to be set before the bin number can be set.

```
recDetail.selectNewLine({
    sublistId : 'inventoryassignment'
});
recDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId : 'inventoryassignment',
    fieldId : 'binnumber',
    value : idBinNumber
});
recDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId : 'inventoryassignment',
    fieldId : 'quantity',
    value : numLineQty
});
recDetail.commitLine('inventoryassignment');
```

Comment: Do you have `location` set?

Comment: Maybe not, I'll try that.

Comment: Is the location on the Inventory Detail or on the Sublist?

Comment: on item sublist